# If there's no name/value pair, how can the server capture the 'submit' action?

Tags: html

I am following the tutorial of [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp),
reference to the 'Name Attribute', it says "Each input field must have a name attribute to be submitted."

However, in the official exmaple, type submit input does not follow the rule.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If there's no name/value pair, how can the server capture the 'submit' action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of what not to do.

> Each input field must have a name attribute to be submitted.
>   If the name attribute is omitted, the data of that input field will
>   not be sent at all.
>   This example will only submit the "Last name" input field:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```